# How are questions linked?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

[A question of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30032/how-safe-is-ubuntu) just got edited, where a link to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1069/6228) was provided.

The edit's log tells it was done by a moderator. So, is this done by a script, or are people doing it manually?

What are conditions to create such links? (my guess is because the questions are similar)

Comment: That is a moderator adding the link, not a script. Moderators are human beings on SE (which may come as a surprise, I know :-P). The mod must have added that at his or her own discretion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I see. I thought they added a new feature. Looked cool at first glance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both questions do seem related, though not duplicates of each other.

I can't talk on behalf of the user who did that (fact they're a moderator is not really relevant, any high rep member can edit any post they want) but you can simply ask them by leaving a comment on your own question there (that was edited) starting with `@` followed by their display name, thus they'll get a notification about your comment.

Generally speaking, high rep members and moderators sometimes do such things to make the overall content better and improve searchability.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The fact that he modified the questions doesn't bother me at all. Was wondering if it was a new feature

Comment: Cheers, you can always see details by clicking the "edited [x] [y] ago" time stamp in your case it's [this page](http://askubuntu.com/posts/30032/revisions) - and "system" edits are made only by special account aka [Community User](http://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community). :)